# Installing error with graphlab in ubuntu

Tags: python, graphlab

I have followed https://dato.com properly and installed graphlab, But when try to import graphlab in ipython it's not working still showing

```
ImportError: No module named graphlab
```

What's the Problem.

Answer (score 0):

That error often happens because graphlab-create is installed in a different environment than the one you're working in. Are you using Miniconda or virtualenv by any chance? If so, make sure to activate your working environment, then download and install graphlab-create, then import in IPython, Jupyter notebook, etc.